# Did the miracles which attested to Rivka's quality remain when Rachel joined the family?

Tags: candle-lighting

Did the [miracles](http://www.secretofchallah.com/50708/Blessing-in-the-home) of the candle's remaining lit all week, the challah's staying blessed and the cloud hovering, which resumed when Rivka was brought home by Yitzchak also happen by when Yaakov married Rachel? If they were a testament to Rivka's quality, why would a woman who married Yaakov not merit them?

Answer (score 1):

The Medrash you mention is in [Medrash Raba 60:16](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01633_part_5.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2)

> כָּל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיָה עָנָן קָשׁוּר עַל פֶּתַח אָהֳלָהּ, **כֵּיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה פָּסַק אוֹתוֹ עָנָן**, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזַר אוֹתוֹ עָנָן. כָּל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיוּ דְּלָתוֹת פְּתוּחוֹת לִרְוָחָה, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה שָׂרָה פָּסְקָה אוֹתָהּ הָרְוָחָה, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזְרָה אוֹתָהּ הָרְוָחָה. וְכָל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיָה בְּרָכָה מְשֻׁלַּחַת בָּעִסָּה, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה שָׂרָה פָּסְקָה אוֹתָהּ הַבְּרָכָה, כֵּיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזְרָה. כָּל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיָה נֵר דּוֹלֵק מִלֵּילֵי שַׁבָּת וְעַד לֵילֵי שַׁבָּת, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה פָּסַק אוֹתוֹ הַנֵּר, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזַר. **וְכֵיוָן שֶׁרָאָה אוֹתָהּ שֶׁהִיא עוֹשָׂה כְּמַעֲשֵׂה אִמּוֹ**, קוֹצָה חַלָּתָהּ בְּטָהֳרָה וְקוֹצָה עִסָּתָהּ בְּטָהֳרָה, מִיָּד וַיְּבִאֶהָ יִצְחָק הָאֹהֱלָה.‏

It mentions 2 points that may answer your question:

1. The 3 miracles stopped when Sarah died - כֵּיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה פָּסַק - and Rivka managed to reinstate them. OTOH: When Rachel & Leah married Yaakov, Rivka was still alive, so they couldn't reinstate them. (And even though they were in a different country, the miracles were "owned" by Rivka, so they couldn't "take them over" the way Rivka did.)
2. Once Yitzchak saw that Rivka was pious enough to recreate the miracles - כֵיוָן שֶׁרָאָה אוֹתָהּ שֶׁהִיא עוֹשָׂה כְּמַעֲשֵׂה אִמּוֹ -  he agreed to marry her; an unknown foreigner.
   OTOH:  Yaakov had chosen Rachel without any signs and therefore didn't need any miracles to persuade him to marry her.